# Hash attack: find strings of length 2^N with same hashCode()

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hash, hashcode

Reading algorithms fourth edition by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne I found the following question:

> Hash attack: find 2^N strings, each of length 2^N, that have the same hashCode() value, supposing that the hashCode() implementation for String is the following:

```
public int hashCode() {
   int hash = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
      hash = (hash * 31) + charAt(i);
   return hash;
}
```

> Strong hint: Aa and BB have the same value.

What comes on my mind is generating all possible strings of length 2^N and compare their hashCodes. This, however, is very expensive for large N and I doubt it's the correct solution. 
Can you give me hints what I miss in the whole picture?

Comment: *"Can you give me hints"* Yes, hint: Read the "Strong hint".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andreas' and Glains' answers are both correct, but they aren't quite what you need if your goal is to produce 2<sup>*N*</sup> distinct strings of length 2*N*.

Rather, a simpler approach is to build strings consisting solely of concatenated sequences of `Aa` and `BB`. For length 2×1 you have { `Aa`, `BB` }; for length 2×2 you have { `AaAa`, `AaBB`, `BBAa`, `BBBB` }, for length 2×3 you have { `AaAaAa`, `AAaaBB`, `AaBBAa`, `AaBBBB`, `BBAaAa`, `BBAaBB`, `BBBBAa`, `BBBBBB` }; and so on.

(Note: you've quoted the text as saying the strings should have length 2<sup>*N*</sup>. I'm guessing that you misquoted, and it's actually asking for length 2*N*; but if it is indeed asking for length 2<sup>*N*</sup>, then you can simply drop elements as you proceed.)

Answer (score 2):

"Strong hint" explained.

> Strong hint: Aa and BB have the same value.

In ASCII / Unicode, `B` has a value 1 higher than `A`. Since those are the second last characters, the value is multiplied by `31`, so hash code is increased by `31` when you change `xxxxAa` to `xxxxBa`.

To offset that, you need last character to offset by `-31`. Since lowercase letters are 32 higher than uppercase letters, changing `a` to `A` is `-32` and changing one letter up to `B` is then `-31`.

So, it get same hash code, change second-last letter to next letter (e.g. `A` to `B`), and change last letter from lowercase to next uppercase (e.g. `a` to `B`).

You can now use that hint to generate up to 26 strings with the same hash code.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a look at the `hashCode()` implementation and the given hint:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
        hash = (hash * 31) + charAt(i);
    return hash;
}
```

We know that `Aa` and `BB` produce the same `hash` and we can easily verify that:

- `(65 * 31) + 97 = 2112`
- `(66 * 31) + 66 = 2112`

From here on, `hash` is the same for both inputs. That said, we can easily append any amount of characters to both strings and you will always receive the same value.

One example could be:

- `hashCode("AaTest") = 1953079538`
- `hashCode("BBTest") = 1953079538`

So, you can generate enough hash values by just appending the same sequence of characters to both strings, more formally:

```
hashCode("Aa" + x") = hashCode("BB" + x)
```

Another note on your idea to generate all possible strings and search for duplicates. Have a look at the [bithday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) and you will note that it will take much less to find duplicate hash values for different inputs.

- It will be very difficult to find the original hashed value (indeed, you would have to try out all possible inputs if the hash algorithm is good).
- Duplicate hash values are rare (there have to be duplicates since the hash has a fixed length). If a duplicate is found, the duplicate should be *meaningless* (random characters), so it cannot be abused by an attacker.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a closer look at the hash function, it works like a number system (e.g. Hexadecimal) where the weight of the digits is 31. That is, think of it as converting a number to base 31 and that makes your final hash code something like `hashCode = (31^n) * first-char + (31^n-1) * second-char + ..... + (31^0) * last-char`

The second observation is that the ASCII distance between the capital and the small letter is 32. Explained in terms of the hash function, it means that when you replace a capital letter by a small one, it means you are adding 1 more to the higher digit and 1 to your current digit. For example:

`BB = (31)(B) + (31^0)B` which also equals `(31)*(B - 1) + (31^0)*(31 + B)` notice that I have just taken one unit from the higher digit and added to the lower digit without changing the overall value. The last equation equals to `(31)*(A) + (a) == Aa`

So, to generate all of the possible String of a given hash code, start with the initial String and shift the character from right to left by replacing a small character by the capital one while decreasing one from the higher location (where applicable). You can run this in O(1)

Hope this helps.